# Location of roots of a Quadratic Equation

Tags: quadratics

**Question:**

For what values of $m\in\mathbb R$, the equation $2x^2-2(2m+1)x+m(m+1)=0$ has exactly one root in the interval $(2,3)$?

**My Approach:**

As the leading coefficient of the equation is positive, its graph would be an upwards opening parabola. This implies that $f(2)>0$ and $f(3)<0$

From $f(2)>0$, we get:

$$m^2-7m+4>0$$
which gives us

$$m\in(- \infty,\frac{7-\sqrt{33}}{2})\cup(\frac{7+\sqrt33}{2},\infty)$$
From  $f(3)<0$, we get:
$$m\in(\frac{11-\sqrt73}{2},\frac{11+\sqrt73}{2})$$
Intersecting the above two intervals, I get:
$$m\in(- \infty,\frac{7-\sqrt{33}}{2})\cup(\frac{7+\sqrt33}{2},\frac{11+\sqrt73}{2})$$

However, the correct answer is:
$$m\in(\frac{7-\sqrt{33}}{2},\frac{11-\sqrt73}{2})\cup(\frac{7+\sqrt33}{2},\frac{11+\sqrt73}{2})$$$$
I can't figuire out how it is correct, even after finding out the values. Please help.

Comment: Your intersection is not correct.

Comment: I know that, but I can't understand why.

Comment: I think $f(3) \lt 0$ is not correct since there would be two roots , one in $(2,3)$ and other $\gt 3$

Comment: You are missing the case where the axis of the parabola is less than $x\lt 2$. Consider $f(2)f(3)\lt 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible cases.

Case 1. $f(2) \lt 0$ and $f(3) \gt 0$.

OR

Case 2. $f(2) \gt 0$ and $f(3) \lt 0$.

Also, I think the intersection of the two zones mentioned will be a continuous one.

Here is a diagramatic representation of the solution

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is exatly one root in $(2,3)$ if $f(2)>0>f(3)$. But it is also true that there is exatly one root in $(2,3)$ if $f(2)<0<f(3)$. It seems that you missed that possibility.

Comment: Actually, there would be a root in $f(2)<0<f(3)$ if the leading coefficient of the equation would be negative and not positive.

Comment: Why is that? Can you justify it?